# Consistent placement of attributes - interface, class or both?

Tags: c#, interface, coding-style, attributes

I've noticed that it's been bothering me lately that when I'm advancing into a project, I always end up with a bunch of attributes that decorate the method declarations in the interface **but also** a different set of decorating the method implementations.

The latest instance is this WCF I'm working with and there, I'm only going to have a single implementing class. Still, some attributes populate the interface, while others do the class. Is that considered bad coding style?

More specifically - can/should all the attributes be moved into the implementing class definition when working with WCF?

Comment: Can you give a few concrete examples? Your question is a bit vague and abstract without it.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure if I can give a good example, because my question is of a general nature regarding coding-style. Am I to understand that there's no convention regarding placement of attributes and that it's governed by ad-hoc approach of what works in a given case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specific to WCF:

You can't move all the attributes to Implementing class alone, as the `WCF Contract` is defined by the interface and it is the interface that is exposed to the WCF Clients which are used for discovery of the WCF services and metadata.

Also, `Attributes` are used by the .Net runtime using reflection and they are used to discover and apply metadata to various [`AttributeTargets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which include `interface`, `class` etc.

So, I think it is Ok to use `Attributes` in both interfaces and classes and not considered a bad practice provided the `.Net runtime` *requirement* is dependent on the target where they are used.